# Filter XSS by regular express

Tags: php

I use ckeditor and open `source` item to user, therefore they can type something like `<script>alert(1)</script>` in it, in the front-end we usually use `htmlspecialchars` to filter the HTML tag, but I need to let other html effect edited by user who correctly, therefore I need to write a function to filter all script tag to prevent xss attack.

#### PHP

```
$content = 'This is the content <script>first</script> and <script>second</script> gogo';
$pattern = '/<script>(.*)<\/script>/i';
$content = preg_replace($pattern, '&lt;script&gt;$1&lt;/script&gt;gt;', $content);
echo $content;
```

This is what I tried to do, but totally wrong, I need to convert `<sctipt>` and `<script        >` to `&lt;script&gt;`

Comment: Wordpress uses [kses](https://sourceforge.net/projects/kses/). Maybe take a look at that. For something as sensitive as this and the fact that you are coming to StackOverflow asking for a regex that would do it would indicate that you *probably* don't know what you're doing (no offense). I would just leave it up to the experts and use something open source and under active development instead of trying to roll your own. Here's another link worth checking out: http://htmlpurifier.org/comparison

Comment: What about `<img src="..." onload="XSS" />`? Or  `<div onmouseover="XSS">`? Or `<a href="javascript:XSS">`? There are many ways around your attempted filter.

Comment: Thanks for your reminding, I will try kses

Comment: Also, have you considered using [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/)? That's what StackOverflow uses. According to a 10 second Google search it appears there's a markdown plugin for ckeditor.